# Compare divs and get the index of the tallest

Tags: jquery, each

I want to find out which div of the same class is the tallest (in terms of height of course).  I am looking to achieve this with `.each()` function so I can get the index of the tallest and apply some CSS (like changing the background color) later on. Is this possible or is there a better way?

Comment: Did you try anything? e.g. with `.height()`?

Comment: order by descending, get top 1 ???

Comment: Sorry it wasn't explained very well. Yes I tried height(). I think my real problem is the images on the divs, seems the images height are not counted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/remus/8RekD/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tallest;
    var max = 0;
    $('div').each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).height() > max) {
            max = $(this).height();
            tallest = index;
        }
    });
    alert(tallest + " is the tallest at " + max + "px");
});
```

Comment: thanks r3mus I tried your solution its working well. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/SvHgP/). then I use `:eq()` selector to target and apply css.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to work:

```
var max = 0;
var maxElement;
$('.someclass').each(function(d) { 
    if (d.height() > max) {
       max = d.height();
       maxElement = d;
    }
});
// then do something with maxElement
```